# Why don't we wait if there is no patrons, in this decision tree from Russel and Norvig's book?

Tags: decision-trees, norvig-russell

I'm reading Russel-Norvig's book about artificial intelligence and now at chapter decision tree where this figure is shown:

[image]

So far I understood it. This decision tree should answer the question if we have to wait for a table or not. Obviously we don't have to wait if there are no patrons and if the restaurant is full, it depends on the waiting time. If it is 0-10 then we wait but if it is longer than 60min then we don't have to wait?

But why do we have to wait if there are some patrons? I mean there will be free tables, so why do we have to wait?

Then I try to change the question to "should we wait?" Then it makes more sense. If it is just 0-10min we should wait but if it is longer than 60min we should not. If there are some patrons, then it is ok we can wait. But the case "None" doesn't make sense. Why don't we wait if there is no patrons? What are the reasons? Bad restaurant?

Answer (score 0):

If a restaurant doesn't have patrons, it means that it has received a lot of complaints that's why the None means don't wait. In general, complaints based on preference also serve a purpose as they start to show a pattern that can be interpreted as disapproval from a good portion of your clientele.

That's why the absence of patrons makes sense.